# Flutter testing problem with validation via GlobalKey<FormState>

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

Hi everyone I'm running some tests I have

```dart
await tester.pumpWidget(app);
expect(formKey.currentState.validate(), true);
```

And I keep getting that `validate` was called on null. Is there something I need to do between pumping the widget that contains the `Form` which is app and calling `validate`

Here is the function that gives me app

```dart
MaterialApp createApp(GlobalKey<FormState> key, TriggeredTextFormField field) =>
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Form(
          key: key,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              field,
              RaisedButton(child: Text('Submit'),onPressed: key.currentState.validate)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just changed `onPressed: key.currentState.validate` to `onPressed: () {key.currentState.validate();}`